# Server Side Validation in Orchard CMS Dynamic Forms Module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I need to do some server side validation with some of my forms built using the dynamic forms module. What's the best way to do this? Through workflows?

Specifically, we are getting spam in a customer form and I want to filter out those that include web address in the message field.

Comment: Input validation can be done in the dynamic forms itself. It you want to steer and act on results, workflow would be the best place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a Decision to my workflow before the Email action that let me enter C# code into the script field. Here is the code I used in the Decision script field.

```
var message =  "#{FormSubmission.Field:message}";
if (message.ToLower().Contains("http://") || message.ToLower().Contains("https://")) {
    SetOutcome("Spam"); 
}
else {
    SetOutcome("Real"); 
}
```

If the message was real, I sent the email. If not, I just end the process.